# ON DELETE trigger in SQL Server 2008 affects more rows than intended

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have the following simplified DB model:

[image]

There are plans with jobs. Jobs contain the objectids of locations, but they are not explicitly associated with the table `Location`.

I have an `ON DELETE` trigger for the table `Location`. I want the trigger to reset the `objectid`'s of the jobs to -1.

```
update dbo.Job 
set objectid = -1, lat = -1, lng = -1, location = null 
from
   (dbo.[Plan] as p 
    inner join dbo.Job as j on (p.planid = j.planid 
                                and p.userid in (select user_id from deleted)))
    inner join deleted as d on j.objectid = d.objectid
```

My problem:

This trigger resets **all** matching objectids, even if the job belongs to a different `aspnet_Users`. How can I achieve that only jobs of the corresponding `aspnet_User` are affected by the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use both the `objectid` and `userid` columns with joins and not with `IN` operator.

Also, I don't see why `aspnet_Users` should be added:

```
update 
        dbo.Job 
set 
        objectid = -1, lat = -1, lng = -1, location = null 
from
        dbo.Job as j 
    join
        dbo.Plan as p   on  p.planid = j.planid
    join
        deleted as d    on  d.objectid = j.objectid
                        and d.user_id = p.userid ;
```

Comment: Objectid is not the primary key, so different users will have different locations with the same objectid - objectids are unique only for the same user. The problem with my trigger was, that locations from different users where affected.